# Fetch two sets of distribution metrics with GCP MQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, charts, monitoring, dashboard, mql

I want to fetch and plot multiple sets of metrics, and the GCP MQL example does not seem to work with 'join'. I'm using log-based distribution metrics.

Does anyone have experience of using MQL in GCP monitoring and importing/fetching multiple sets of distribution metrics?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.